# OpenText Content Suite Platform: Database table for finding Type of user

Tags: opentext

We need to write a report to find the number of below categories of users on our OpenText Content Suite Platform installation:

Content Suite Platform Read-Only Named Users
Content Suite Platform Standard Named Users
SAP Extended ECM by OpenText Professional Users

Can somebody please point me to the MSSQL DB table where this information about the type of user is stored.

Answer (score 1):

First you have to understand what these license means, what privilege does a user get with each of this license.

For eg.,

> ***Content Suite Platform Read-Only Named Users*** - User can only access
>   documents. (No permission to upload documents and users cannot
>   participate in any Workflows).
>   Based on this understanding, we have to
>   query KUAF and DTREEACL table to identify users who have only See,See Content permission on Content Server objects.

Answer (score 0):

This will show you your standard users

```
Use ContentServerDatabaseName
SELECT COUNT(Name) FROM kuaf WHERE Deleted=0 AND TYPE=0
```